# How to update one Gitlab project from another project

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

On my Gitlab installation, I have a library project that creates a Java jar file which I want to use in other projects. I would like to be able to update another project whenever I make changes in my jar library.

I am using Maven to compile and package the jar file, and I am also using Maven in my pipeline for the other project. Both the jar file and the application jar are artifacts generated by the pipeline. I believe that I should be able to automatically copy the library jar from its target folder into the folder used by my dependent project.

Problem is, ,I don't know how to do this. I have read a lot of CI/CD documentation for Gitlab and have not been able to find anything about how to update a project so that it can use a library generated from another project.

Has anyone done this before? Can someone tell me how to cause an update to my application project whenever I make changes to the jar in my library project?

Comment: Usually, the better approach for this is to use a multi-module project.

Comment: Usually there's one of two scenarios: either the two projects are related strongly to each other, then they should probably live in the same repository, or they don't then one should just publish the artifacts (maybe to a private repo, if you don't want it to be public) and the other should "pull" the updated dependency, potentially through some automation like renovatebot or similar. Hand-grafted ad-hoc solutions like you describe are rarely the best idea.

Answer (score 3):

Given the scenario you are describing, a good approach is to use multi-project pipelines. If yours projects look like this:

- Project A: Packages and uploads jar to Gitlab
- Project B: Downloads package generated by Project A

Then by using a multi-project pipeline, you can trigger a new pipeline on your Project B as soon as the artifact is created, ensuring that it'll exist and that your pipeline won't break because of a race condition. Moreover, you can even [fetch generated artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#fetch-artifacts-from-an-upstream-pipeline) from the Project A pipeline directly, instead of having to read from any Package Registry.

All the related documentation can be found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#multi-project-pipelines)

Comment: Actually, I had read the documentation you are referring to prior to posting my question because I wanted to learn about setting up multi- project pipelines in order to use the jar from my project A to rebuild my project B. The problem with the documentation is that it does not give clear instructions on how to get the library artifact into the repository used for the application. That is why I posted this question. I need to know exactly how to copy my library from Ptoject A into Project B. I need to be able to do this since I am using Maven POMs to do the build.

Answer (score 1):

@bhito has a good answer. I will add a couple of words.

It's mostly better to push all artifacts from PROJECT_X (like Jar files you have) into the registry (like Artifactory, Nexus, etc.) with the appropriate concrete version. Then, specify a dependency in PROJECT_Y with that version, and in this way, trigger the project's pipeline by git-committing without building complex GitLab downstream pipelines. One more benefit, you definitely ensure that always pin lib's versions.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have two isolated projects. Let's call them "library_project" and "main_project".

The first thing you need to do is **publish** the "library_project". To do that, you have two options:

- Publish it locally by doing a `mvn clean install`
- Publish it to a package registry:

  - For example, for GitLab you can use the following the guide: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/

After that, you will need to configure your "main_project" to use that library. To do that there are two steps you will need to do:

- Configure the Maven to read from the registry were you have your library is published by updating the maven settings:

  - For GitLab you can follow the same guide: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/
  - For locally published libraries you may need to build the "main_project" with offline mode. Meaning: `mvn -o clean package`. Please, note that any non already downloaded dependencies will fail on offline mode. There's a guide here with more details here: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-offline
- Once you have configured your setting you can import the library as any other library